# Converting column values into columns with values

Tags: pandas

I Have a dataset that looks like this

```
name  | qualification|
liken | BSc          |
liken | Diploma      |
liken | Certificate  |
lakey | matric       |
```

and I want to transform it to look like this

```
name  | BSc | Diploma | Certificate| matric |
liken | 1   |    1    |    1       |   0    |
lakey | 0   |    0    |    0       |   1    |
```

in pandas. I tried get_dummies but it does not give the desired result.

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['name'], df['qualification'])`?

Comment: It seems to have worked thank you